# How to connect a programming language to an IDE

Tags: code-editor

I am using a scripting language named AutoIt. It has an IDE named SciTE editor. But it lacks a lot of features. So i have planned to make one. I have the basic knowledge to make a GUI with a multi line text editor and add some auto complete features to that code editor. But how can i run the code in the text area with my programming language ? That means, when my user types code in that editor and presses 'Run'button, then i need to run the code he typed in the editor.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What language are you writing the GUI in? What language are you trying to run? What have you tried so far? What code do you currently have?

Comment: You're going to need AutoIt's compiler. Plus do a lot more research if you're really going to build an IDE. Also the user should have to save the file as a file type so the compiler knows what it's compiling.

Comment: @horns i have a plan to make it in vb.net or in Autoit. I havn't tried anything now. I need to make sure that it is possible to run a compiler in my program.

Comment: If it is a scripting language that is being written, you'll want the run button to call the interpreter for that language as a new process. If it's a compiled language, you'll have to run the compiler, possibly a linker, and then the compiled program. The sematics for starting a new process depend on the language you are writing the GUI program in.

Comment: @horns starting compiler is ok. But how can i connect the user typed code with the compiler ?

Comment: After all, it is a scripting language

Comment: You probably will need to have it saved to disk, and then pass the filename to the compiler/interpreter

Comment: That, that is the point i am asking about. How can i pass my filename to the compiler ?